# Why Kotlin Spinner onItemSelected doesn't work when on a Fragment which loads another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, fragment, spinner

I have Fragment and Fragment loads another fragment in it's FrameLayout.And I also have a Spinner in that main Fragment.

PS:my mainActivity initiliaze ListFragment()

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navigator = ListNavigateImpl(this)

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putSerializable(ListFragment.KEY.KEY_NAVIGATOR,navigator )

        val fragment = ListFragment()
        fragment.arguments = bundle


        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

If I don't load any other fragment to my Framelayout or load any fragment except it's own fragment my spinner's methods doesn't work.In other words my spinner only works when I load it's own fragment to Framelayout.It is like fragment display it's own fragment in it's FrameLayout.This is the only way my spinner methods works.But I want to display my recyclerview on framelayout and my spinner works.Is there any way display my fragment and make my spinner methods working at same time?

This is when I display my recyclerview on FrameLayout but my spinner methods don't working.(onItemSelected method and other methods like this don't trigger even I choose an option from spinner)

[image]

The code below for that situation this is my **FragmentList.kt** and it's xml name is **fragment_list.xml**

```
class FragmentList:Fragment(R.layout.fragment_list) {
    private lateinit var viewModel: CharacterViewModel
    private lateinit var filterFragment: FilterFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        filterFragment= FilterFragment()
        viewModel= CharacterViewModel()
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            viewModel.getData()

        }

        viewModel.users.observe(this, Observer { characterList ->
            Log.d("CHARACTER",characterList.results.toString())
            Recyclerview1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
            Recyclerview1.adapter = Adapter(characterList.results)


        })





    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        val t=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
        val spinner = t.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.sp_status)
        var list=resources.getStringArray(R.array.status)

        spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list)


        Log.d("ALPHA","${spinner}")
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Log.d("LAMBDA","I HAVE BEEN SELECTED")
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"SELECTED ${parent.getItemAtPosition(position)}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                Log.d("DELTA","NOTHING SELECTED")

            }
        }


        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false)
    }
}
```

my **fragment_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F1D30F"
    android:id="@+id/fragmetListLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_status"
        android:entries="@array/status"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        ></Spinner>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        ></FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

my recyclerview is loading to FrameLayout in **List_Fragment.kt**

**List_Fragment.kt**

```
class ListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_list) {
    private lateinit var viewModel: CharacterViewModel
    private lateinit var filterFragment: FilterFragment
    object KEY {
        const val KEY_NAVIGATOR = "NAVIGATOR"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        filterFragment= FilterFragment()
        //viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CharacterViewModel::class.java)
        /*val bundle = this.arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            val navigator : ListNavigator = bundle.getSerializable(KEY_NAVIGATOR) as ListNavigator
            navigator.navigateFilter()
        }*/

    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("MARS","I AM WORKING HUH?")

            val transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.content,FragmentList())
            transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
            transaction.commit()

    }

}
```

Even I don't load anything to framelayout,spinner still doesn't work.But if I load same fragment to FrameLayout it works.
I just just changed to return statment with

```
return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false)
```

to

```
val t=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
return t
```

And with that modification I got intresting display but my spinner methods works.
[image]

Only spinner which is below(Inside the FrameLayout) is working.

How can I fix that?Whatever I do spinner is just up to it's own fragment display on FrameLayout.How can I prevent that?
I want to display my recyclerview and my spinner works same time on fragment.

Comment: where is `sp_status` initialized?

Comment: It doesn't initiliaze indeed I just use it in xml android:entries="@array/status" so far.

Comment: your code snippet doesn't show variable `sp_status` and how its initialized.  If this var is null then your `onItemSelected` listener won't work

Comment: But it is an element from xml.How can I initiliaze it?

Comment: How can I initiliaze and make it not null?

Comment: Yeah it returns null but how can I define it as not null?

Comment: `var sp_status: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.sp_status)`

Comment: It's not null anymore but it doesn't initialize the onItemSelected still.